# Why is my def function in Python not working?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to save some data from a table in a CSV file.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Main function
def getContent(link):
    #Request content
    result1 = requests.get(link)

    #Save source in var
    src1 = result1.content

    #Activate soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src1,'lxml')

    #Look for table
    table = soup.find('table')

    #Save in csv
    with open('averageheight.csv','w',newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for tr in table('tr'):
            row = [t.get_text(strip=True)for t in tr(['td','th'])]
            writer.writerow(row)


#LINKS
getContent('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_human_height_by_country')
```

The error I'm getting:

```
  File "c:/Users/Agent 1/Desktop/Datapackages/Average Height/process.py", line 31, in <module>
    getContent('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_human_height_by_country')
  File "c:/Users/Agent 1/Desktop/Datapackages/Average Height/process.py", line 27, in getContent
    writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Users\Agent 1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2044' in position 24: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: I ran your code and no errors and a very nice pandas table from the csv. Here are the versions i'm running:  request.__version__ '2.22.0',  bs4.__version__  '4.8.1'

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the ascii characters to `utf-8`. Use the below modified line of code:

```py
row = [(t.get_text(strip=True)).encode('utf-8') for t in tr(['td','th'])]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ran your code on my machine and found no errors. However, you may want to consider specifying `encoding='utf-8'` to `with open(...) as f`.

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Main function
def getContent(link):
    #Request content
    result1 = requests.get(link)

    #Save source in var
    src1 = result1.content

    #Activate soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src1,'lxml')

    #Look for table
    table = soup.find('table')

    #Save in csv
    with open('averageheight.csv','w',newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for tr in table('tr'):
            row = [t.get_text(strip=True)for t in tr(['td','th'])]
            writer.writerow(row)


#LINKS
getContent('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_human_height_by_country')
```